# Custom URL generation with HTML forms

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am new to HTML. I need code that generates and redirects to a URL depending on the value of form input elements. For example, with two fields `name` and `roll`, once populated it should generate `http://example.com/name/roll` and send the user to the URL.

Is this possible? I was able to create the URL `http://webaddress/data+data+data` but not with `/`. Please guys; if you may help, it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of question is relating to JavaScript and PHP. Also, you're a little too broad. Mind showing us some of your code, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On front-end, this will be best done with JavaScript, simply fetch the values in the form and insert it in the URL as you desire.

**Sample HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction();return false">
  <input name="name" id="name">
  <input name="roll" id="roll">
</form>
```

**Sample JavaScript**

```
<script>
 function myFunction(){
    //Get values
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var roll = document.getElementById('roll').value;
    //Redirect
    window.location = "http://webaddress/"+name+"/"+roll;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = "Jone"
var roll = 100;

var url = "http://webaddgess/"+name+"/"+roll;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this One

```js
var roll=document.getElementById("rollhtml");
var x = document.getElementById("namehtml");
var url="Your URL here"+roll+x;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rollhtml" placeholder="Roll" value="">
<input type="text" id="namehtml" placeholder="Name">
```